# Jquery Cookie и фон страницы

Tags: jquery, cookie, css

Есть код:

```
$('#change-orange').click(function(){
    var background = $('.demo-1 .gt-grid .messages').css('background-color', '#fc644d');
    var font_social = $('.demo-1 .gt-grid .messages .social-panel div').css('color', 'white');
    var panel = $('#panel').css('background', '#1abc8a');
    $.cookie('color', background);
});
```

потом я вызываю $.cookie('color'), что я неправильно делаю?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

пробуй так

```
$('#change-orange').click(function(){
    var background = '#fc644d';
    $('.demo-1 .gt-grid .messages').css('background-color', '#fc644d');

    var font_social = $('.demo-1 .gt-grid .messages .social-panel div').css('color', 'white');
    var panel = $('#panel').css('background', '#1abc8a');

    $.cookie('color', background);
});

if($.cookie('color')) {
    $('#panel').css('background', $.cookie('color'));
}
```

Comment: а можно делать например if($.cookie('color') === 'orange'){ .. ?

Comment: канэшн =) только вы потестируйте работает ли оно без глюков)) а то я не пробовал)

Comment: хотя нет, стоп. оно походу вообще не должно работать... туплю что-то.. сейчас перепишу код

Comment: @foozzi, обновил ответ, только подгоните код как вам нужно

Comment: спасибо, помогло